# Memory leaks when using PHP script to open and close socket from Asterisk Manager

Tags: php, sockets, asterisk

I'm using asterisk ami to open a socket and send commands to the asterisk server for specific tasks. As far as i can tell the socket is opened, the command is sent, the socket is then closed. However, my memory usage on the asterisk machine increases slightly over time until it comes to a point where i have to restart the httpd service. It isn't much code but i'm new to php so i'm not sure what is wrong or if i should be looking elsewhere.

```
<?php
echo $sipexten = $_REQUEST["sipexten"];
echo $xferext = $_REQUEST["xferext"];

$wrets = "";
$amiusername = 'XXX';
$amisecret   = 'XXX';
$socket = '';       

//MAIN PROCESS       
//quit if any parameters are missing
if ($sipexten == '' || $xferext == ''){
    exit('not enough parameters');   //stop further processing for not enough     parameters
}

ob_implicit_flush(true);
$socket = fsockopen("127.0.0.1","5038", $errno, $errstr, 0);    
$wrets = fread($socket,30);
fputs($socket, "Action: Login\r\n");
fputs($socket, "UserName: $amiusername\r\n");
fputs($socket, "Events: off\r\n");
fputs($socket, "Secret: $amisecret\r\n\r\n");
fputs($socket, "Action: CoreShowChannels\r\n\r\n");
fputs($socket, "Action: Logoff\r\n\r\n");        
while (!feof($socket)) {
    $wrets .= fread($socket,8192 );
}
fclose($socket);   

$sipexten = "Channel: SIP/$sipexten";
$channelVal = strpos($wrets,$sipexten);
if ($channelVal){
    $channel=trim(substr($wrets,$channelVal+9,strpos(substr($wrets,$channelVal),"UniqueID:")-9)    );
}


ob_implicit_flush(true);
$socket = fsockopen("127.0.0.1","5038", $errno, $errstr, 0);    
$wrets = fread($socket,30);
fputs($socket, "Action: Login\r\n");
fputs($socket, "UserName: $amiusername\r\n");
fputs($socket, "Events: off\r\n");
fputs($socket, "Secret: $amisecret\r\n\r\n");
fputs($socket, "Action: Atxfer\r\n");
fputs($socket, "Channel: $channel\r\n");
fputs($socket, "Exten: $xferext\r\n");
fputs($socket, "Priority: 1\r\n\r\n");
fputs($socket, "Action: Logoff\r\n\r\n");        
while (!feof($socket)) {
    $wrets .= fread($socket,8192 );
}
fclose($socket); 
echo "<br />";         
echo $wrets;
?>
```

Here is what my other script looks like:

```
<?php

$sipexten = $_REQUEST["sipexten"];

$command = $_REQUEST["command"];

$isgood = $_REQUEST["isgood"]; 

$subfolder = $_REQUEST["subfolder"];

$srcname = $_REQUEST["srcname"];

$dstname = $_REQUEST["dstname"];


$wrets = "";
$amiusername = 'XXX';
$amisecret   = 'XXX';
$sipchannel = '';

$audiofolder = '/var/lib/asterisk/sounds/customaudio2play/';
$badfolder = 'bad';
$goodfolder = 'good';
$recordingformat = 'gsm'; 
$socket = '';        


if ($command == 'start'){  
    if ($sipexten == '' || $subfolder == '' || $srcname ==''){
        exit('not enough parameters');   //stop further processing for not enough parameters
    }
    //Check if SIP/sipexten is having a call. If yes, proceed.

    $sipchannel = amigetchannel();

    if ($sipchannel != '') {

        //AMI LOGIN


        // don't buffer output... flush it immediately
        ob_implicit_flush(true);
        $socket = fsockopen("127.0.0.1","5038", $errno, $errstr, 0);    
        $wrets = fread($socket,30);
        //AMI Login
        fputs($socket, "Action: Login\r\n");
        fputs($socket, "UserName: $amiusername\r\n");
        fputs($socket, "Events: off\r\n");
        fputs($socket, "Secret: $amisecret\r\n\r\n");
        fputs($socket, "Action: Monitor\r\n");
        fputs($socket, "Channel: $sipchannel\r\n");
        fputs($socket, "File: $audiofolder/$subfolder/$srcname\r\n");
        fputs($socket, "Format: $recordingformat\r\n");
        fputs($socket, "Mix: 1\r\n\r\n");

        //LOG OFF AMI
        fputs($socket, "Action: Logoff\r\n\r\n"); 
        while (!feof($socket)) {
            $wrets .= fread($socket,8192 );
        }
        fclose($socket);  
        echo $wrets;
        echo ('start executed');
    } else {
        //No channel found
        echo ('No active channel');
    }       //$sipchannel != '';    
    //DONE

} elseif ($command == 'stop'){
    if ($sipexten == ''){
        exit('not enough parameters');   //stop further processing for not enough parameters
    }

    //Get current channel of $sipexten
    $sipchannel = amigetchannel();

    if ($sipchannel != '') {


        //AMI LOGIN
        // don't buffer output... flush it immediately
        ob_implicit_flush(true);
        $socket = fsockopen("127.0.0.1","5038", $errno, $errstr, 0);    
        $wrets = fread($socket,30);
        //AMI Login
        fputs($socket, "Action: Login\r\n");
        fputs($socket, "UserName: $amiusername\r\n");
        fputs($socket, "Events: off\r\n");
        fputs($socket, "Secret: $amisecret\r\n\r\n");
        fputs($socket, "Action: StopMonitor\r\n");
        fputs($socket, "Channel: $sipchannel\r\n\r\n");

        //LOG OFF AMI
        fputs($socket, "Action: Logoff\r\n\r\n"); 
        while (!feof($socket)) {
            $wrets .= fread($socket,8192 );
        }
        fclose($socket);  
        echo $wrets;

    }
    echo ('stop executed');
} elseif ($command=='showchannels') {

    echo ('</br> sip channel: ' . amigetchannel());

}

echo ('</br>End of file');


function amigetchannel(){


    global $sipexten, $amiusername, $amisecret;

    // don't buffer output... flush it immediately
    ob_implicit_flush(true);
    $socket = fsockopen("127.0.0.1","5038", $errno, $errstr, 0);    
    $wrets = fread($socket,30);
    //AMI Login
    fputs($socket, "Action: Login\r\n");
    fputs($socket, "UserName: $amiusername\r\n");
    fputs($socket, "Events: off\r\n");
    fputs($socket, "Secret: $amisecret\r\n\r\n");

    fputs($socket, "Action: CoreShowChannels\r\n\r\n");

    //LOG OFF AMI
    fputs($socket, "Action: Logoff\r\n\r\n"); 
    while (!feof($socket)) {
        $wrets .= fread($socket,8192 );
    }
    fclose($socket);  

    $needle = "Channel: SIP/" . $sipexten;
    $channelVal = strpos($wrets,$needle);

    if ($channelVal){
$sipchannel=trim(substr($wrets,$channelVal+9,strpos(substr($wrets,$channelVal),"UniqueID:")-9));
            }

}


?>
```

Comment: So the question is why the memory usage on the server that this script sends a command to is getting higher? Not about why this script eats more and more memory? Since this script is not a long running script?

Answer (score 0):

Use top or ps utility to check which process use memory, after that debug your code for memory leaks.

If apache use memory, check your httpd.conf, there is paramter "MaxRequestsPerChild" which can be used to restart buggy thread.

```
<IfModule worker.c>
StartServers         2
MaxClients         150
MinSpareThreads     25
MaxSpareThreads     75
ThreadsPerChild     25
MaxRequestsPerChild  0
</IfModule>
```